# Using reset method with $meteor.object

Tags: javascript, angularjs, meteor

I have a simple controller with the [angular-meteor starter project](http://angular-meteor.com/tutorial/step_06).

```
controller("PartyDetailsCtrl", function($scope, $stateParams, $meteor) {
  $scope.party = $meteor.object(Parties, $stateParams.partyId);
  $scope.save = function() {
    $scope.party.save();
  };
  $scope.reset = function() {
    $scope.party.reset();
  };
})
```

And the related view:

```
<input ng-model="party.name">
<input ng-model="party.description">

<button ng-click="save()">Save</button>
<button ng-click="reset()">Reset form</button>
<button ui-sref="parties">Cancel</button>
```

My reset function here doesn't reload the document from the server, it ends up saving it. Say the document says "Test Alpha", in the form I change the form to "Test Beta", then press the reset button. "Test Beta" is now the document in the server. Am I misunderstanding how the `reset()` function should work on a meteor object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ran through the tutorial too quickly. There's a third parameter that needs to be passed to a meteor object in order to prevent it from being automatically saved after every change. So `$scope.party` should be set to:

```
$scope.party = $meteor.object(Parties, $stateParams.partyId, false);
```

Comment: I'm having the same issue, the save button works but the reset one doesn't do anything or logs any error :(